# Enabling mongo exception translation in spring-data-rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

Following this [tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/), working with [complete](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-mongodb-data-rest/tree/master/complete) code, how do I enable exception translation for mongo?

When my mongo db is down, i'm getting 500 error from `com.mongodb.MongoServerSelectionException`. Shouldn't this be translated into `DataAccessResourceFailureException` with [MongoExceptionTranslator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoExceptionTranslator.html)? Am i supposed to register this bean somehow? I've tried with:

```
@Bean
public MongoExceptionTranslator mongoExceptionTranslator() {
    return new MongoExceptionTranslator();
}
```

but still no change

**EDIT:**

I've created a [demo](https://github.com/airborn/gs-accessing-mongodb-data-rest/tree/abstractMongoConfiguration/complete/src/main/java/hello) with the suggestions from [Stackee007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1604480/stackee007) but still can't get this to work

Answer (score 0):

`MongoExceptionTranslator` is already registered if your configuration registers `MongoFactoryBean` or `SimpleMongoDbFactory`. You could configure mongo something like below which registers `SimpleMongoDbFactory`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class ApplicationConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "yyy";
    }

    @Override
    protected UserCredentials getUserCredentials() {
        return new UserCredentials("abc", "***");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        List<ServerAddress> seeds = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
        seeds.add(new ServerAddress("xxxx"));
        seeds.add(new ServerAddress("xxx"));
        seeds.add(new ServerAddress("xx"));

        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(seeds);
        mongo.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred());
        mongo.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED);
        return mongo;
    }

    @Bean
    public GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new GridFsTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mappingMongoConverter());
    }

}
```

Comment: This didn't help, i'm still seeing MongoServerSelectionException `{"timestamp":1423912384275,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"com.mongodb.MongoServerSelectionException","message":"Unable to connect to any servers","path":"/people"}`

Comment: This is how this looks now https://github.com/airborn/gs-accessing-mongodb-data-rest/tree/abstractMongoConfiguration/complete/src/main/java/hello